# LIBTOOL fails while attempting to compile GMP

Tags: bash, gcc, makefile, gmp, libtool

I am trying to install gmp2 as explained in https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/wiki/InstallingGmpy2 under ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Therefore I need to compile GMP, MPFR, and MPC.

To compile GMP, according to above instructions, I need:

```
$ cd ~/src/gmp-5.1.0
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/case/local
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
```

The ***./configure*** step worked fine, although I had to prefix the command with ***/bin/bash***.

When I invoke the ***make*** command, I run into this error involving libtool:

> /bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP -I.. -DOPERATION_`echo fib_table | sed 's/_$//'`    -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=core2 -march=core2 -c -o fib_table.lo fib_table.c
>   ../libtool: 1581: ../libtool: preserve_args+= --tag CC: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= gcc: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -std=gnu99: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -DHAVE_CONFIG_H: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I.: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I..: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -D__GMP_WITHIN_GMP: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -I..: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -DOPERATION_fib_table: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -m32: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -O2: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -pedantic: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -fomit-frame-pointer: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -mtune=core2: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -march=core2: not found
>   ../libtool: 1: eval: base_compile+= -c: not found
>   libtool: compile: you must specify a compilation command
>   libtool: compile: Try 'libtool --help --mode=compile' for more information.
>   make[2]: *** [fib_table.lo] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nicolas/Dropbox/crypto/gcc-lib/gmp-5.1.3/mpn'
>   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nicolas/Dropbox/crypto/gcc-lib/gmp-5.1.3'
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

I suspect that the libtool call prefixed by ***/bin/sh*** is wrong but I can not figure how to change it:

- In the MakeFile, I changed SHELL=/bin/sh to SHELL=/bin/bash: no difference
- When I "printenv SHELL", I get /bin/bash

Any idea how to complete compiling GMP?

Comment: Did you try: `sudo apt-get install libmpc-dev`?

Comment: Why are you trying to install version 5.1.0 and not 5.1.3 (the latest currently)?

Answer (score 4):

As you say, this happens because calls to `libtool` get prefixed by `/bin/sh` and your `/bin/sh` implementation (my educated guess: `dash`) doesn't implement the `+=` syntax (which is not a POSIX feature). `libtool` itself has `/bin/bash` as hashbang.

If you can't figure out where your `SHELL` prefix comes from you can "fix" `libtool` itself by changing all occurrances of:

```
base_compile+=" ${foo}"
```

to

```
base_compile="${base_compile} ${foo}"
```

Note that this is a quick hack and you should rather fix the underlying problem which is invoking `libtool` with `/bin/sh`.

(I ran into the same problem after switching default shell from `bash` to `dash` due to shellshock when trying to build `apr-util`.)

Comment: Wow, that fixed a lot errors I was having when compiling different stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`apr` invokes a internal libtool under `/usr/share/apr-1/libtool` which is different from the one you normally use.

Probably to avoid environment issues and ironically creating compiler issues: `mv arp-1/libtool` to `apr-1/libtool.bak` and `ln -sv /usr/bin/libtool` to `/usr/share/apr-1/libtool` would fix this regardless of your environment or invocation method.

Similary, check where `libtool` is being called from. A lot of source packages build from internal binaries that may not be compatible with your system.

Answer (score 0):

As the error log says: can't find gcc indicates you don't have gcc ( the gnu c compiler ) installed.
Run `sudo apt-get install gcc && gcc --version`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `libtool-bin` package is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libtool-bin
```

With only `libtool`, `which libtool` command prints `/mnt/c/MinGW/bin/libtool`.

After installing `libtool-bin`, `which libtool` command prints `/usr/bin/libtool`.

This somehow fixed the issue for me, hope this helps someone.